# Alias definition in .perldb (Perl Debugger) for expression evaluation 'x' doesn't work

Tags: perl, debugging

I am wondering if there is a way to define aliases in the Perl Debugger configuration file `.perldb` for the command `x` which dumps expressions.

All the following imaginable varieties of alias definitions doesn't work:

```
cat .perldb
$DB::alias{ 'x0' }    = "x '%states'";             # Does not work
$DB::alias{ 'x1' }    = 'x %config';               # Does not work
$DB::alias{ 'x2' }    = '"x %config"';             # Does not work
$DB::alias{ 'x3' }    = 'x "%config, $foo"';       # Does not work
$DB::alias{ 'x4' }    = 'x "@L"';                  # Does not work
$DB::alias{ 'x5' }    = 'x %config, $foo';         # Does not work
$DB::alias{ 'x6' }    = '"x %config, $foo"';       # Does not work
$DB::alias{ 'xc' }    = 'x %config';               # Does not work
$DB::alias{ 'pFoo1' } = 'print("foo=$var1\n")';    # Works
$DB::alias{ 'pFoo2' } = 'print("$var2\n")';        # Works
$DB::alias{ 'p1' }    = 'print "\$_ =  $_"';       # Works
$DB::alias{ 'code' }  = 's/^.*$/l 1+99999/';       # Works
```

After starting the debugger with 'perl -d script.pl' and display the aliases with `=` I get:

```
code    s/^.*$/l 1+99999/
p1  print "\$_ =  $_"
pFoo1   print("foo=$var1\n")
pFoo2   print("$var2\n")
x0  x '%states'
x1  x %config
x2  "x %config"
x3  x "%config, $foo"
x4  x "@L"
x5  x %config, $foo
x6  "x %config, $foo"
xc  x %config
```

Any ideas if the alias definitions in `.perldb` expect a special syntax or does it just not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not documented, but [the contents of the `%alias` hash are strings that are used as the right-hand side of a `$cmd =~ ...` expression](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/perl-5.28.1/lib/perl5db.pl#L2845-2864). That is, to work as expected, the aliases must be `s///` commands.

Try something like

```
$DB::alias{ 'x1' } = 's/^.*/x %config/';
```

Comment: Awesome! Despite the fact, that it's only viable for dumping a single expression (i. e. variable).  In order to have an alias to dump multiple expression I tried the following command.    `$DB::alias{ 'xc3' } = 's/^.*/x join ",", qw($var1 $var2)/';`  However, the output is not properly formated as it should. Hence, the output using the aliased command gives `0  'FOO,BAR'`

 `x $var1, $var2` and directly invoked in the debugger shell gives two properly formated elements `0  'FOO'
1  'BAR'` in two lines.

Comment: @Phrosch Untested, but that should be `'s/^.*/x \$var1, \$var2/'`.